# how do i check which property is changed on PropertyChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf

I register an event on property changed  like below

```
addedItem.PropertyChanged += OnColumnModified;
```

and the definition for OnColumnModified is as follows

```
private void OnColumnModified(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var modifiedItem = (sender as MarketRecord.FItemExtended);
    if (!modifedFItemsExtended.Contains(modifiedItem)) 
    {
        modifedFItemsExtended.Add(modifiedItem);
    }
}
```

Now I want to check which property of modifiedItem  is changed when this event is triggered . How do I handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

[PropertyChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.aspx) should be what you receive on that event and not it's base `EventArgs`

```
private void OnColumnModified(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) { 
  var modifiedItem = (sender as MarketRecord.FItemExtended);
  var propertyChanged = e.PropertyName;
  if (!modifedFItemsExtended.Contains(modifiedItem))
    modifedFItemsExtended.Add(modifiedItem);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

use PropertyChangedEventArgs instead of EventArgs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.aspx)

```
private void OnColumnModified(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if("Foo".Equals(e.PropertyName)) { /* do stuff here */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is this:

```
e.PropertyName
```

edit: and use `PropertyChangedEventArgs` in stead of `EventArgs`, like otis23 says

Answer (score 0):

First you can change the type of 'e' from EventArgs to PropertyChangedEventArgs. Now you jave a porperty named 'PropertyName' in your e object that contains the property name of the changed property as a string.